# Access 2013 syntax error on INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have the following query in c# and don't have any idea why it shows me this error:

> "syntax error on INSERT INTO statement".

I use Access 2013.

```
OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand();

command2.Connection = connection;           
command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO money (price,cardnum,checknum,dateTime,employeeid) values('" + TempPrice + "','" + TempCriditNum + "','" + TempCheckNum + "','" + dateTimePickerX1.GetSelectedDateInPersianDateTime().ToShortDateString() + "','" + id + "')";
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Please provide the MONEY table's structure and the full error message

Comment: On a side note, consider using parameterized queries (please see [`OleDbParameterCollection.AddWithValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)), your SQL statement is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: @vmachan its the full erro is "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." exception. my and all field are number except dateTime that is datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to check

- dateTime is a reserved word. Try wrapping it in square brackets -
- if the type of data you are dealing with is a Date\Time then you should be wrapping the input in # signs
- if your data types are not strings, do not wrap them in quotes
- as pointed out by Jia Jian, you should use parameterized queries
- as pointed out by HansUp, Money is also a reserved word, so wrap it in square brackets

So the query ends up looking like :

```
command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [money] (price,cardnum,checknum,[dateTime],employeeid) values(" + TempPrice + "," + TempCriditNum + "," + TempCheckNum + ",#" + dateTimePickerX1.GetSelectedDateInPersianDateTime().ToShortDateString() + "#," + id + ")";
```

Comment: thank you for replying. i already tested that but it doesn't work. and that's why i post here.

Comment: Is the data type in the database a datetime or a string? Because you are also wrapping the field in quotes.

Comment: its datetime . Do i miss it?

Comment: yah, datetime should not be wrapped in quotes but in # signs IIRC. You are probably better off using parameterized queries.

Comment: i also use # but i still receive the same error :O

Comment: I just saw your note the all fields are numbers expect for the dattime. Then do not wrap any fields in single quotes.

Comment: thank u but its not matter what i do i get that error again and again

Comment: Can you select from the table? Is it an ownership issue? Do you need to prefix it with an owner like dbo.money or something.

Comment: `MONEY` is also an Access [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#M)

Comment: And so it is, can't believe I totally overlooked that.

Comment: answer updates as per @HansUp

Comment: Upvoted. Was looking at this [page](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Learn-about-Access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2) as well, didn't notice `money` was reserved.

Comment: thanks a lot. its not about the name. i am using solar calender do u think its the reason?

Comment: @sajjad.rezaee wrapping `money` in square brackets `[]` still gives the error? Do you have an example output of a date in the solar calendar?

Comment: @swestner thank u a lot i was missing a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL statement might be prone to SQL injection. Consider using parameterized queries by adding values via the [`OleDbCommand.Parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) property instead of concatenating it.

An example would be:

```
command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [money] (price, cardnum, checknum, [dateTime], employeeid) values(@tempPrice, @tempCreditNum, @tempCheckNum, @dateTime, @id)";

command2.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[] {
           new OleDbParameter("@tempPrice", TempPrice),
           new OleDbParameter("@tempCreditNum", TempCriditNum),
           new OleDbParameter("@tempCheckNum", TempCheckNum),
           new OleDbParameter("@dateTime", dateTimePickerX1.GetSelectedDateInPersianDateTime().ToShortDateString()),
           new OleDbParameter("@id", id)
});

command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This should also solve your syntax error.

Comment: thanks. but the same error occur with this new code :|.

Comment: Can you use oledb with named parameters now? I remember it used to be index based and you needed to use ? in the sql statement and add the parameters the the parameters collection in order. Now that was fun.

Comment: @swestner [yes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)! you still can use `?` in the statement though.

Comment: @sajjad.rezaee see the comments in the other answer, `money` is a reserved keyword. Consider using parameterized queries at the same time!